# Why isn't my python program working?

Tags: python

Im having trouble with my python program as it isn't putting cars over the speed limit into my "illegal" list. Why is this happening? I would also be grateful if you could also post a solution.

```
#start
Illegal=[]
Legal=[]
Count = 1
DIST = 100
TIME = 0
SPEED = 0

def SpeedCheck(TIME):
    global DIST
    SPEED=(DIST/float(TIME))
    #here is a variable i made to make the program more simple

print (" Welcome to the Speed check calculator")
print ("\n")

#program asks the user to add information needed
LIMIT=int(input ("Speed limit (M/S): "))
VAR=int(input ("How many (M/S) should be allowed over the limit?: "))
LIMIT=LIMIT+VAR

while Count==1:

    REG = input ("Enter Registration number: ")
    TIME =int(input("Enter the time that the vehicle was in the zone in seconds (e.g. 1min= 60): "))
    SpeedCheck(TIME)
    #variable used

    if SPEED>LIMIT:
        Illegal.append(REG)

    elif SPEED<=LIMIT:
        Legal.append(REG)

    #desicion
    Count=Count-1


    Count=int(input("Press 1 to continue or 0 to move on: "))





print ("\n")
option=input("Press P to print Legal and illegal cars: ")
if option=="p":
    print ("Legal: \n")
    print (Legal)
    print ("\n \n")
    print ("Illegal: \n")
    print (Illegal)

print("\n Thank you for using the program, Goodbye.")
#end
```

Comment: Could you please choose a more suitable title for your question? Also please fix the syntax highlighting errors at the start of your code.

Comment: Please read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

SPEED is set in SpeedCheck but you have not made it global (you did with DIST) You might wish to consider returning SPEED from the function instead of using a global.

```
def SpeedCheck(timein, distance):
    return distance/float(timein)

...

speed = SpeedCheck(TIME, DIST)

if speed > LIMIT:
    ...
```

A style comment: generally UPPERCASE is reserved for constants, so SPEED is a bit misleading. Take a look at [PEP008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need  `global DIST` in your `SpeedCheck` function since you aren't trying to modify `DIST`. But you *are* modifying the global variable `SPEED` in that function so it *does* need to be declared global to make your code work as intended.

However, its best to avoid using `global` unless you *really* need it (which is rare). For this program,  `SpeedCheck` should return the calculated speed using a `return` statement. Eg,

```
def speed_check(elapsed_time):
    return DIST / float(elapsed_time)
```

---

As others have mentioned, Python has some style conventions regarding names. Plain variables and functions are written in all lower case, with multi-word names separated with underscores, like I did with `speed_check`. ALL UPPER CASE is used for constants. Names that begin with an upper case letter are used for classes, with CamelCase for multi-word names.

The Python syntax highlighting used on Stack Overflow thinks your `Illegal`, `Legal` etc are classes, so it's coloured them in that blue-green colour, which makes it look wrong, or at least a bit confusing.

Comment: `time` is a standard library name, you might wish to change the name of the variable.

Comment: @cdarke: Yeah, I was just thinking about that. :) It's harmless here, but it's still confusing.

Answer (score 0):

you didnot declared speed as GLOBAL

```
def SpeedCheck(TIME):
    global DIST
    global SPEED
    SPEED=(DIST/float(TIME))
    #here is a variable i made to make the program more simple
```